# Why interceptor does run three times?

Tags: java, spring-mvc, spring-boot

```
 public boolean preHandle(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response, Object object) {
    String jwt = request.getHeader("auth");
    String payloadKey = "apitest";
    HandlerMethod handlerMethod=(HandlerMethod)object;
    Class type = handlerMethod.getBeanType();
    if (type.isAnnotationPresent(Auth.class)) {
        try {
            if (jwt == null || !Objects.equals(payloadKey, JwtUtil.parseJWT(jwt).get("info", String.class))) {
                return false;
            }
        }catch (ExpiredJwtException | SignatureException | MalformedJwtException e){
            return false;
        }
    }
    log.info("1");
    return true;
}
```

when jwt is true, but i see log.info("1") run 3 times, why it run 3 times?

my interceptorConfig:

```
@Override
public void addInterceptors(InterceptorRegistry registry) {
    registry.addInterceptor(authenticationInterceptor())
            .addPathPatterns("/**");
}
@Bean
public AuthenticationInterceptor authenticationInterceptor() {
    return new AuthenticationInterceptor();
}
```

i set @Auth on my controller class:
@Auth public class ApiController

And when i clear my preHandle exclude "log.info("1") return true"  that run 3 times

Comment: Maybe you issue multiple requests?

Comment: @EugenCovaci  No  i just request once

Comment: Can you post your project (or a similar  POC) on GitHub?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Updated**

You can debug into `AuthenticationInterceptor`, to confirm somethings:

1. if the `handlerMethod` point different object in total 3 times?
2. if the `AuthenticationInterceptor`, that is `this` variable， is different or not?
3. If there has some redirect for your request?

I tried use some code like yours, it has correct behavior. Can you show more code or a simply way to reproduce the issue?

Comment: You invoke `authenticationInterceptor()` for add interceptor to `InterceptorRegistry`, It would always make a new `AuthenticationInterceptor `, no matter if you  use `@Bean` on method `authenticationInterceptor()`. So it useless.

Comment: What did you say it's plain false. I suggest you read more about Spring Java configuration.

Comment: Yes, with `@Bean` way, spring will only keep the same interceptor. I tried with some code like yours above, the interceptor only invoked once for a request. Can you show more your code or simple way to reproduce the issue